# Having problems compiling Mathematica Cuda code

Tags: compile

Ok I am trying to follow the examples of Cuda Code in the docummentation

Run the `CUDAQ[]` and get back a `True`

and run some of the first examples of Cuda code in the documentation and they also work

but when I try

```
doubleFun = CUDAFunctionLoad["
  __global__ void doubleVec(mint * in,  mint length) {
      mint index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;  
        if (index < length)
          in[index] = 2*in[index];
    }", "doubleVec", {{_Integer}, _Integer}, 256]
```

This example is to multiply a vector by 2

I get the following error code

```
CUDAFunctionLoad::noxcomp: A C compiler was not found in specified directory `1`. 
Set"XCompilerInstallation" to the directory containing a supported C compiler.    
Supported C compilers are detailed in the NVCCCompiler documentation page. >>
```

It looks like mathematica does not know where my C compiler is at and needs to be define 
I look in the documentation and I do not see how to do that.
I am using OS X for Mac and from the above error message they are asking me to set

XCompilerInstallation to the directory containing the C compiler, I also have installed XCode. What should I do next?

Comment: Try running `Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];CCompilers[]` and also read [this tutorial on installing a C compiler](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html). See also `NVCCCompiler[]`

Comment: What does `CUDACCompilers[]` give? An empty list?

Comment: By the way, welcome to Mathematica.SE! If you consider visiting this place regularly we'd appreciate if you could choose some kind of user name more distinguishable than user+number. I don't like to be a number, and almost certainly you don't either.

Comment: Sjoerds Yes if I run CUDACCompilers[] I get an empty list {}

Comment: I should state the obvious. My machine got a Cuda capable Nvidia card. The driver number is CUDA Driver Version: 4.2.10

Comment: @YnceraJ Just that you know you're not alone: while researching this question I got the same problems as you. Although I'd swear it had worked before nothing worked. Not only CUDA compilation didn't work but also general compilation.

Comment: One cause in my case was that an update to visual studio express that I was running in combination with the particular SDK disabled or removed the compilers, and that disables the CUDA compilation capability too. It took me a day to discover cause and solution, but I'm still in the process of getting CUDA compilation back to life. I know you're on a Mac but something similar may have happened to you as well.

Comment: What does running `Needs["CCompilerDriver"];CCompilers[]` give?

Comment: @YnceraJ, `"XcompilerInstallation"` is an option to `CUDAFunctionLoad`, so you could try adding `"XCompilerInstallation" -> "path"` to your `CUDAFunctionLoad` call, where *path* is the path to the compiler you have installed.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I had what sounds like the same problem, installing the VS Express Service Pack removes the 64 bit compiler. To get everything working I had to follow the exact instructions in the readme for the compiler [update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422), i.e uninstall everything and reinstall in the specified order.

Comment: HAve you had any luck finding the COmpiler. I get a CC1pluss error. I can not figure what is wrong. I am using Mathematica 9.1 with Redhat RHEL 6.6